# Error #1294 - Inválido ON UPDATE cláusula para campo 'fecha_act'

Tags: mysql

No entiendo. Tuve que recurrir al viejo confiable PHPMyAdmin para hacer la transacción de una base de datos, pero me da este error.

Trabajo de navicat y hago datatransfer remotamente y nunca había tenido problemas, hasta ahorita al hacerlo así.

Consulta SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `categorias` (
  `id` tinyint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categoria` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `fecha_act` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

> #1294 - Inválido ON UPDATE cláusula para campo 'fecha_act'

Answer (score 1):

Como dice la [documentación para MySQL 5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

> Before MySQL 5.6.5, support for automatic initialization and updating
>   is more limited:
>
> - `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` cannot be used with `DATETIME` columns.

Traducción libre:

> Antes de MySQL 5.6.5, la inicialización y actualización automática era más limitada:
>
> - `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` y `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` no se pueden usar con columnas de tipo `DATETIME`.

Aparentemente estás usando una versión de MySQL anterior a 5.6.5.  Para corregir el error, tus opciones son:

- Usa una versión más reciente de MySQL,
- Cambia el tipo de la columna de `DATETIME` a `TIMESTAMP`, o
- Usa un trigger para poner la columna al día de forma automática.